# Linear Regression Overlaid on plot with holes in data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, linear-regression

I've been desperately trying to simply add a linear regression to show up on this plot. However using scipy.stats.linregress it turns out that printing res.intercept results in "nan." I don't know why this is happening.

The code is very messy since I am a n00b and also have leftover commented out code from when I tried using np.polyfit and got an error involving length of the values not fitting into the cereal_df when I tried to cereal_df.insert

I suspect that an issue that might be causing the "nan" issue is that my data set has holes in it. So there will be lots of cells in the xslx file that are empty before there are more cells that appear. This might also be causing the issue with different lengths. I just want it to work one way or another. Here is the abomination of a python code that I came up with.

```
#importing is important
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as pit
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import stats

# These are the colors that will be used in the plot
color_sequence = ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c',
                  '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5',
                  '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f',
                  '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf', '#9edae5']

#locate the file path
path = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.5\\extra\\T8-CMD3.xlsx"

#skiprows=11 bc first row read must have titles or else freaks out
#creating object and calling it to read the csv file
cereal_df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=11)
cereal_df

#some uwu plot style shwag
plt.style.use('ggplot')

#getting data ready to be plotted
y = cereal_df['Adjusted Metal Loss']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
cereal_df['Adjusted DateTime'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(cereal_df['Adjusted Dates'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
x = cereal_df['Adjusted DateTime']
xx = cereal_df['Adjusted Dates']
v = cereal_df['Direct Reading']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
cereal_df['real direct reading date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(cereal_df['Direct Reading Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
w = cereal_df['real direct reading date']

#create/configure figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('17E T8 CMD3 Metal Loss Over Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Metal Loss (Mils)')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (Years)')
ax.set_xlim(dt.date(2014, 1, 1), dt.date(2022, 1, 1))
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)

#linear regression
#model = np.polyfit(cereal_df['Adjusted Dates'],y,1)
#f = np.poly1d(model)
#cereal_df.insert(1, 'Linear Regression', model, allow_duplicates = False)
res = scipy.stats.linregress(xx, y)
#cereal_df.insert(1, 'Linear Regression',  res.intercept + res.slope*x)
print res.intercept

#make plot and show plot are two distinct functions
#plt.plot(x,y,'o', ms=3, mec = color_sequence[1], color=color_sequence[1])
#plt.plot(w,v, 'o', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[5], color=color_sequence[5])
#plt.plot(x, cereal_df['Linear Regression'], ms=3, mec = color_sequence[1], color=color_sequence[1])
#plt.plot(x, res.intercept + res.slope*x, 'o', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[5], color=color_sequence[5])
#plt.plot(xxx,yyy, '-g', label='did this even flipping work or nah')




#must put legend after generating plot
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think that you'll need to do some processing on the pandas side before plotting. Check what are the data types of your columns to see if they were imported correctly,remove rows where there's a Nan either on X or Y,then run the regression.

Comment: Check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html and the `na` options in `read_excel` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: `xxx = xx[bool_series]
yyy = y[bool_series]
res = scipy.stats.linregress(xxx, yyy)
print res.intercept
print res.slope`

I was able to make a separate array from which to perform the linear regression. Still unsure on how to remove the rows that have NaN values from the dataframe itself but this works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here I resolved the linear regression issue I had and overlaid four linear regressions above their respective raw data. The regression shows although since it is piggybacking off of the dataframe and there are gaps in the dataframe it does not show across the entire span of the plot. Instead it will cut off when the dataframe data does as well. I believe this is only a minor aesthetic issue that I may resolve later.

```
#importing is important
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as pit
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import sys
import scipy
from scipy import stats

# colorful colors for coloring 
color_sequence = ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c',
                  '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5',
                  '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f',
                  '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf', '#9edae5']

#locate the file path
path = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.5\\extra\\17W\\T2-CMD1.xlsx"

#some uwu plot style shwag
plt.style.use('ggplot')

#create/configure figure and axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_title('17W T2 CMD Metal Loss Over Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Metal Loss (Mils)')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (Years)')
ax.set_xlim(dt.date(2014, 1, 1), dt.date(2022, 1, 1))
ax.set_ylim(0, 20)

#skiprows=11 bc first row read must have titles or else freaks out
#creating object and calling it to read the csv file
cereal1_df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=11)
milk1_df = pd.read_excel(path, 'Direct Reading', skiprows=1)

#getting data ready to be plotted
c = cereal1_df['Adjusted Metal Loss']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
cereal1_df['Adjusted DateTime'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(cereal1_df['Adjusted Dates'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
a = cereal1_df['Adjusted DateTime']
b = cereal1_df['Adjusted Dates']

#identify which rows are filled with Null values
#so that the next command can remove
bool_series = pd.notnull(cereal1_df['Adjusted Metal Loss'])

#creating an array without the NaN values so that scipy doesn't freak out
d = b[bool_series]
e = c[bool_series]
res = scipy.stats.linregress(d, e)
slope = res.slope * 365
title = ('CMD1 decays at ' + str(slope) + ' mils/year')

#now inserting into dataframe our lovely linear regression using scipy derived info
cereal1_df.insert(1, 'Linear Regression', res.intercept + res.slope*d)
#so now when z is shown in the third plot y-axis it is to plot our linear regression
#and of course we will use the same x-axis that is in the proper datetime frame
z = cereal1_df['Linear Regression']

f = milk1_df['Mils']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
milk1_df['real direct reading date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(milk1_df['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
g = milk1_df['real direct reading date']

#make plot and show plot are two distinct functions
plt.plot(a,c,'o', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[5], color=color_sequence[5], label = 'T2 CMD 1 Metal Loss')
plt.plot(g,f, 's', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[4], color=color_sequence[4], label = 'T2 CMD 1 Direct Reading')
plt.plot(a,z, '--', ms=5, mec = color_sequence[6], color=color_sequence[6], label=title)

#must put legend after generating plot
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels)


#
#rinse and repeat with CMD2
#

#locate the file path
path = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.5\\extra\\17W\\T2-CMD2.xlsx"

#skiprows=11 bc first row read must have titles or else freaks out
#creating object and calling it to read the csv file
cereal_df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=11)
milk_df = pd.read_excel(path, 'Direct Reading', skiprows=1)


#getting data ready to be plotted
y = cereal_df['Adjusted Metal Loss']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
cereal_df['Adjusted DateTime'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(cereal_df['Adjusted Dates'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
x = cereal_df['Adjusted DateTime']
xx = cereal_df['Adjusted Dates']

#identify which rows are filled with Null values
#so that the next command can remove
bool_series = pd.notnull(cereal_df['Adjusted Metal Loss'])

#creating an array without the NaN values so that scipy doesn't freak out
xxx = xx[bool_series]
yyy = y[bool_series]
res = scipy.stats.linregress(xxx, yyy)
slope = res.slope * 365
title = ('CMD2 decays at ' + str(slope) + ' mils/year')

#now inserting into dataframe our lovely linear regression using scipy derived info
cereal_df.insert(1, 'Linear Regression', res.intercept + res.slope*xxx)
#so now when z is shown in the third plot y-axis it is to plot our linear regression
#and of course we will use the same x-axis that is in the proper datetime frame
z = cereal_df['Linear Regression']

v = milk_df['Mils']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
milk_df['real direct reading date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(milk_df['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
w = milk_df['real direct reading date']


#make plot and show plot are two distinct functions
plt.plot(x,y,'o', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[1], color=color_sequence[1], label= 'T2 CMD 2 Metal Loss')
plt.plot(w,v, 's', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[0], color=color_sequence[0], label= 'T2 CMD 2 Direct Reading')
plt.plot(x,z, '--', ms=5, mec = color_sequence[2], color=color_sequence[2], label=title)

#must put legend after generating plot
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels)


#
#rinse and repeat with cmd3
#


#locate the file path
path = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.5\\extra\\17W\\T2-CMD3.xlsx"

#skiprows=11 bc first row read must have titles or else freaks out
#creating object and calling it to read the csv file
cereal11_df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=11)
milk11_df = pd.read_excel(path, 'Direct Reading', skiprows=1)

#getting data ready to be plotted
cc = cereal11_df['Adjusted Metal Loss']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
cereal11_df['Adjusted DateTime'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(cereal11_df['Adjusted Dates'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
aa = cereal11_df['Adjusted DateTime']
bb = cereal11_df['Adjusted Dates']

#identify which rows are filled with Null values
#so that the next command can remove
bool_series = pd.notnull(cereal11_df['Adjusted Metal Loss'])

#creating an array without the NaN values so that scipy doesn't freak out
dd = bb[bool_series]
ee = cc[bool_series]
res = scipy.stats.linregress(dd, ee)
slope = res.slope * 365
title = ('CMD3 decays at ' + str(slope) + ' mils/year')

#now inserting into dataframe our lovely linear regression using scipy derived info
cereal11_df.insert(1, 'Linear Regression', res.intercept + res.slope*dd)
#so now when z is shown in the third plot y-axis it is to plot our linear regression
#and of course we will use the same x-axis that is in the proper datetime frame
z = cereal11_df['Linear Regression']

ff = milk11_df['Mils']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
milk11_df['real direct reading date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(milk11_df['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
gg = milk11_df['real direct reading date']

#make plot and show plot are two distinct functions
plt.plot(aa,cc,'o', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[7], color=color_sequence[7], label = 'T2 CMD 3 Metal Loss')
plt.plot(gg,ff, 's', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[8], color=color_sequence[8], label = 'T2 CMD 3 Direct Reading')
plt.plot(aa,z, '--', ms=5, mec = color_sequence[9], color=color_sequence[9], label=title)

#must put legend after generating plot
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels)



#
#repeat with cmd4
#


#locate the file path
path = "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.5\\extra\\17W\\T2-CMD4.xlsx"

#skiprows=11 bc first row read must have titles or else freaks out
#creating object and calling it to read the csv file
cereal111_df = pd.read_excel(path, skiprows=11)
milk111_df = pd.read_excel(path, 'Direct Reading', skiprows=1)

#getting data ready to be plotted
ccc = cereal111_df['Adjusted Metal Loss']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
cereal111_df['Adjusted DateTime'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(cereal111_df['Adjusted Dates'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
aaa = cereal111_df['Adjusted DateTime']
bbb = cereal111_df['Adjusted Dates']

#identify which rows are filled with Null values
#so that the next command can remove
bool_series = pd.notnull(cereal111_df['Adjusted Metal Loss'])

#creating an array without the NaN values so that scipy doesn't freak out
ddd = bbb[bool_series]
eee = ccc[bool_series]
res = scipy.stats.linregress(ddd, eee)
slope = res.slope * 365
title = ('CMD4 decays at ' + str(slope) + ' mils/year')

#now inserting into dataframe our lovely linear regression using scipy derived info
cereal111_df.insert(1, 'Linear Regression', res.intercept + res.slope*ddd)
#so now when z is shown in the third plot y-axis it is to plot our linear regression
#and of course we will use the same x-axis that is in the proper datetime frame
z = cereal111_df['Linear Regression']

fff = milk111_df['Mils']
#converting excel time into datetime for plotting date
milk111_df['real direct reading date'] = pd.TimedeltaIndex(milk111_df['Date'], unit='d') + dt.datetime(1900,1,1)
ggg = milk111_df['real direct reading date']

#make plot and show plot are two distinct functions
plt.plot(aaa,ccc,'o', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[10], color=color_sequence[10], label = 'T2 CMD 4 Metal Loss')
plt.plot(ggg,fff, 's', ms=4, mec = color_sequence[11], color=color_sequence[11], label = 'T2 CMD 4 Direct Reading')
plt.plot(aaa,z, '--', ms=5, mec = color_sequence[12], color=color_sequence[12], label=title)

#must put legend after generating plot
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles, labels)
legend = plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```